# How Can I Create A Border In My 2-Column Form?

Tags: html, forms, css, styles, multiple-columns

On my website I have a 2-column reservation form. One part of the form I have tables, so I put in two columns but I want to have a divider between them but I can't figure out a way to do so.

I researched ways how to fix it by adding a divider in the css, but it's not working.

I put the form into 'fiedlset' mode.

This is the CSS layout:

```
    <style>         


    fieldset{

    background-color: #52854C;
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: white;
    border: 2px black solid; 
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius:15px;
     border-radius: 15px;

    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 2px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 2px #999;
    -khtml-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 2px #999;
     box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 2px #999;
     }



    </style>
```

This is the HTML Form:

```
    <fieldset>

        <p><label>Full Address:<input type="text" id="rtstreet" name="rtstreet" style="margin:5px; width:320px; height:15px"></label></p></center>

                    <table>

                    <td><label>Airport Name:</label><input type="text" id="airport" style="width:70px; height:15px">

                    <td><label>Airline Code/Name:</label><input type="text" id="airport" style="width:45px; height:15px">

                    <td><label>Flight #:</label><input type="text" id="airport" style="width:35px; height:15px">



            </table>

           </div>


     <div style="float:right list-style:none;">

      <ul li><h1 class="lead" style="font-weight:bold; color:black;list-style:none;">Drop-Off Information</h1></ul li>

   <p><label>Full Address:<input type="text" id="rtstreet" name="rtstreet" style="margin:5px; width:320px; height:15px"></label></p></center>

                    <table>

                    <td><label>Airport Name:<input type="text" id="airport" style="width:70px; height:15px">

                    <td><label>Airline Code/Name:<input type="text" id="airport" style="width:45px; height:15px">

                    <td><label>Flight #:<input type="text" id="airport" style="width:35px; height:15px">



            </table>


    </div>  

            <br>
            <br>
           </br>
           </br>
           </fieldset>
```

Any help/advice or tips would be really helpful!

Comment: html code would help a lot, also give tr/td ids and apply border to them. What you're applying is outside borders not inner borders

Comment: Thank you, I have an outside border already, I wanted the inside to just divide or put space between 'Pick-Up Information' and 'Drop- Off Information' @ThePlatypus

Comment: yea, give tr/td ids and add border-right/border-left/border-top/border-bottom accordingly

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is you're giving border to the outer edge of the fieldset. You need to appoint individual ids to the tr/td tags and then give the appropriate values in css :

```
border-left
border-right
border-top
border-bottom
```